# Haskell как передать функции в качестве аргумента отрицательное число

Tags: haskell

Начал изучать хаскель и столкнулся с проблемой,в учебнике дали функцию првоерки на знак числа,при передаче функции положительного,либо 0,она работает нормально,как только передаю отрицательное,она начинает ругаться на минус

> :62:1: error:
>       • No instance for (Num (Integer -> Integer))
>           arising from a use of ‘-’
>           (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
>       • In the expression: test - 5
>         In an equation for ‘it’: it = test - 5

Comment: `-5` без пробела. Или может это как раз то место где стоит написать `(-5)`

Comment: Да,точно,скобочки,не подумал об этом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как подсказал @u_mulder, надо писать в моем случае `test (-5)`